# Grouping a datetime column by date in a legacy database using ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm starting to work with ActiveRecord outside Rails to handle a legacy MySQL database that I cannot alter. I want to group rows of a table by date, but AR takes the whole datetime field and not just the date part. What I've tried so far is:

```
raw_data = Order.group(:date_add).sum(:total_products).to_a
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group` by a SQL expression instead of just a column, so write a SQL expression that returns the datetime's date and `group` by that:

```
raw_data = Order.group("date(date_add)").sum(:total_products).to_a
```